# Copy multiple sheets to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, xlsx, worksheet

I have some code that will copy a sheet and then create a new workbook and then paste it and adjust the sheet name and workbook name before saving it to the Desktop.

All the called subs do is transpose ranges of data from the entry sheet to the export sheet which is the one that is copied (named "Rows") to be pasted into the new workbook.

Code is used as a button and so far no declaration has been required.

```
Sub UploadSheet()

    Call TransposeHS
    Call TransposeOrigin
    Call TransposeValues
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")
    Worksheets("Rows").Cells.Copy

    Workbooks.Add (xlWBATWorksheet)
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "Rows"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & "\" & "Upload" & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Exported to Desktop"

End Sub
```

How do I adjust the code to copy over 2 sheets instead of just the one into a new workbook?

Comment: Your posted code does  not show (almost) anything relevant... No any variable declaration, your code calls three subs, which we cannot know what they do, you do not say anything about the second sheet (name) and so on. I am afraid that nobody can help you just looking to your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new workbook with `Workbooks.Add` and then pasting is overcomplicated.

Call `Copy` on the worksheet(s) without specifying any parameters; a new workbook is created with the copied sheet(s), and is the `ActiveWorkbook`.

```
Worksheets(Array("Rows", "SecondSheet")).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & "\" & "Upload" & ".xlsx"
```

Comment: Didin't know it would create a new workbook like that. That's exactly what I meant thank you.